# Log probability in the Viterbi algorithm (handling zero probabilities)

Tags: model, hidden, markov, part-of-speech, viterbi

I am coding a probabilistic part of speech tagger in Python using the Viterbi algorithm. In this context, the Viterbi probability at time t is the product of the Viterbi path probability from the previous time step t-1, the transition probability from the previous POS tag to the current POS tag and the emission probability of the observed word given the POS tag. I am computing this by at each word in the sentence looking at each tag/state that is possible at this time (from the observed training data) and then for each possible tag computing the most likely path to this state given by the Viterbi probability explained above. A straightforward psuedo-code implementation can be found [here](https://svn.spraakdata.gu.se/repos/richard/pub/statnlp2015_web/tagger.py).

One practical problem of repeatedly multiplying probabilities is that it may lead to underflow. One solution that is often proposed in the literature is to use log probabilities. As far as I understand, you should do:

```
current_probability = math.log(emission_probability) + math.log(transition_probability) + previous_probability
```

instead of

```
current_probability = emission_probability * transition_probability * previous_probability
```

given that the three probabilities are stored in the corresponding variables.

One problem I am finding hard to grasp, however, is what to do when the emission probability or the transition probability is 0. [Michael Collins writes](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Emcollins/cs4705-fall2018/notes-on-logs.pdf): "One issue with the new algorithm is that log 0 = −∞. Some care is required to deal with probability values equal to 0. A simple solution is to set log 0 = −B where B is a large number."

What large number should I use? `-math.inf`?

Answer (score 0):

one way to handle this is to add some smoothing like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdNgP.png
where,

local variables

word_tag : count of word in training corpus.
tag_total : Number of words which tagged as given as TAG i.e.P(word|TAG)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).